# ¿Puedo crear una función que retorne un número que será parámetro de un cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

a ver si me podéis echar un cable. La idea es pasar por parámetro al procedimiento el nombre y apellidos de un atleta para al final obtener el número de veces que ha hecho podium (Esto lo haría seleccionando las veces que competir.posicion están entre 1 y 3). En una tabla tengo los datos de los atletas y en otra tabla tengo los datos de las pruebas y se relacionan atleta.dorsal = competir.dorsal_atl.

He pensado que se podría hacer una función que tome el nombre y apellidos que se pasan al procedimiento para que devuelva el dorsal que se pasará al cursor. La verdad es que me estoy liando bastante. Se agradece una manita ;)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE nivel(nombre atleta.nombre%TYPE, apellidos atleta.apellidos%TYPE)
is
    function dorsal_atleta (nom VARCHAR2, ape varchar2)
        return number is
        dorsal_at number;
    begin
        select dorsal into dorsal_at from atleta
        where nom = nombre and ape = apellidos;
        return dorsal_at;
    end dorsal_atleta;

    CURSOR c_atleta (dorsal number) IS
        SELECT posicion
        FROM competir
        WHERE dorsal = dorsal_atleta
        GROUP BY atleta.dorsal;
        v_atleta c_atleta%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    ...
END;
```

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún tipo de error?

Comment: Tres, de hecho:

12/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure The symbol "function was inserted before "CURSOR" to continue.

12/37     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:     return 
23/0      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure

Comment: Prueba declarando el cursor antes de la declaración de la función.

Comment: Lo he liado demasiado. Con una modificación de la solución que aporta abajo el compañero sale bien y de manera más eficiente. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si es requisito usar una función y un cursor pero se puede resolver con un simple select-into (está sin probar eh :-D):

```
create or replace function tacataca(p_nombre varchar2, p_apellidos varchar2) return number is

res number;

begin

select count(*) into res from atleta a, competir c where a.dorsal = c.dorsal and posicion in (1,2,3) and nombre = p_nombre and apellidos = p_apellidos;

return res;

end;
```

Comment: Genius! Con alguna modificación lo clavo =)